# CSS - Selecting A element in wordpress custom menu

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to clean up some custom CSS in a custom theme which highlights a wordpress custom menu for a current navigation page (ie; 'Contact' menu item is highlighted when viewing the 'Contact' page).

The current CSS is referencing the ID of each custom menu to apply the styles as per below with a copy for each custom menu:

```
#nav_menu-8.widget .current-page-item > a
{}
```

I'm trying to understand why the style doesn't apply when trying to select the same element without referencing the ID nav_menu-8, ideally something a bit more dynamic than static references:

```
.widget .current-page-item > a
{}
```

When the above CSS is in place - the style is not applied as I would expect (to any A element which has a parent of class current-page-item inside class widget).

Would love to see where I'm going wrong!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple general reasons why it wouldn't work;
a) the element structure in the html doesn't match your selector in the css.
b) the styles applied are being overwritten by a different classes styling that has a higher specificity value. 
I have no idea if that is the case in your example but they are the first two things that come to mind. Try inspecting the element in your browser to see if your selector is being referenced at all. And whether the particular styles are being overwritten by existing styles.

Comment: Perfect!
Thanks for the heads up, I added !important to each of the styles and this has overridden the conflicting CSS - Thanks for changing my direction of thinking, I honestly didn't think about a conflicting setting!

Comment: That's great. Try finding the conflicting css so that you can adjust your new css to overwrite that for this specific element so that you dont have to use "!important". Always limit the amount of times you use "!important" as it can make things difficult later on.